# ШУГАРИНГ - назва процедури, яку не варто перекладати?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Цікавить слово **шугаринг** - переклад-транслітерація з англ.

> Sugaring
>
> 2 method of removing unwanted hair by applying a mixture of lemon
>   juice, sugar, and water to the skin and then peeling it off together
>   with the hair.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sugaring)

Є ще кілька варіантів перекладу:

*епіляція цукром*

*цукрова епіляція*

*цукрування*

Останнє викликає сумніви, бо під час епіляції відбувається накладання цукрової маси на шкіру, а не додавання кудись цукру. СУМ дає значення *посипати*, *класти*.

[ЦУКРУВА́ННЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/cukruvannja), я, сер. Дія за значенням цукрувати
[ЦУКРУВА́ТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/cukruvaty), ую, уєш, недок., перех. Посипати цукром, класти в що-небудь цукор.

Особисто вважаю, що запозиченими словами треба користуватися в тій формі, в якій вони прийшли, якщо нема достатньо близького відповідника.

**Цукрування** може бути відповідником?

Плюси:

1. морфемний склад підтримує семи цукор і дія
2. словникове слово
3. зручне

Мінуси:

1. нема відтінку значення, який би вказував на особливість процедури (накладання на шкіру, а не додавання кудись)
2. не має відтінку модної процедури, тобто не виконує маркетингового призначення

Щодо останнього: це все-таки назва послуги, тому важливо, щоб у назві чітко відстежувалося значення новизни, оскільки в маркетологів улюблений спосіб привернути увагу - так зване очуднення.

Отже, чи варто вживати **цукрування**, а чи **шугаринг** добре функціонуватиме?

Comment: "Особисто вважаю, що запозиченими словами треба користуватися в тій формі, в якій вони прийшли, якщо нема достатньо близького відповідника." А ви знаєте про купу неолоґізмів того ж 19 сторіччя, початку 20 сторіччя?

Comment: До того ж, якщо щодо "g" наприкінці слова можна сперечатися, то перше "g" точно треба передавати через "ґ".

Comment: @P. Vovk авжеж я знаю про неолоґізми, давайте створимо один такий замість шугаринґу. Якщо у вас є можливість науково довести правильність/доречність неолоґізму, гадаю, цей ресурс підтримає відповідь. Зараз я так зрозуміла, відповіді у вигляді вигаданих слів без наукового підґрунття небажані або не приймаються. Дякую за ґ, до речі.

Answer (score 1):

Спробую запропонувати варіант.
Згідно до [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) "шугаринг" може ще називатися як епіляція цукром, карамельна епіляція, персидська епіляція. А в [Словнику чужомовних слів Штепи](https://storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1312) є відповідник до цього слова - "волосопад".

На основі цих слів можна запропонувати такі варіанти як "**цукровий волосопад**" чи "**карамельний волосопад**".

Comment: Якось мені *волосопад* не подобається, бо тут немає явної дії ззовні. Може *волососмик*?

Comment: Гадаю, що можливий і такий варіант)

Comment: Тоді можна скоротити взагалі до цукросмику. І я це пропоную без сарказму.